# How can I add resources with dataSource in Scheduler Kendo MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, telerik

In this [demo](https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/scheduler), the Room resources are added with BindTo, but I'd like to add resources with the dataSource.

I changed BindTo to

```
 .DataSource(d => d.Read("GetRooms", "Scheduler"));
```

My problem is, I didn't now how to write the GetRooms method in the controller, to do the same, as bindTo. I'm new in using Kendo, I didn't see this before, so any suggestion would be great. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

From what I see in the original example, `Read()` method accepts arguments of corresponding action method & controller name to set data source, which has `Read` method in `SchedulerController` like this:

```
public virtual JsonResult Read([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
{
    return Json(taskService.GetAll().ToDataSourceResult(request));
}
```

What you want to do is returning JSON data to scheduler (populating scheduler's data) by using `ToDataSourceResult` method, hence you can write `GetRooms` method inside `SchedulerController` in a similar way (suppose `Rooms` is a POCO class with parameterless constructor):

```
public partial class SchedulerController : Controller
{
    // other stuff

    public virtual JsonResult GetRooms([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
    {
        // do something with Rooms data
        var rooms = new Rooms(); // this declaration can be moved to `SchedulerController` constructor like `taskService` does
        var roomList = rooms.GetAll();
        DataSourceResult result = roomList.ToDataSourceResult(request);

        // return JSON result
        return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

    // other stuff

}
```

Then you can use `DataSource` as shown below:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Scheduler<Kendo.Mvc.Examples.Models.Scheduler.TaskViewModel>()
      // other stuff
      .DataSource(d => d.Read("GetRooms", "Scheduler"))
      // other stuff
)
```

Reference:

[KendoUI: Understanding ToDataSourceResult](https://doylestowncoder.com/2014/04/14/kendoui-understanding-todatasourceresult/)

Comment: Thank you! I tried this. My problem is, that I use the Scheduler, and I'd like to change the BindTo when I add the resources, like in the demo (resources.Add () ...) If I use DataSource there instead of BindTo, the DataSource (read method), later in my program won't work.

Comment: I think you want something like `resource.Add(m => m.OwnerID).Title("CustomTitle").DataTextField("TextField").DataValueField("ValueField").DataColorField("ColorField").BindTo("SourceArray")`. Is that source array retrieved from DB values or another array? Please explain where `BindTo` should take values from.

Comment: Yes, I'd like to do this, source array is from the DB. May I use ViewData for that?